# Function CNN model written in Keras 2.2.4 not learning in TensorFlow or Keras 2.4

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I am dealing with an object detection problem and using a model which is actually functioning (its results have been published on a paper and I have the original code). Originally, the code was written with **Keras 2.2.4** without importing TensorFlow and trained and tested on the same dataset that I am using at the moment. However, when I try to run the same model with TensorFlow 2.x it just won't learn a thing.

I have tried importing everything from **TensorFlow 2.4**, but I have the same problem if I import everything (layers, models, optimizers...) from **Keras 2.4**. And I have tried to do so on two different devices, both using a GPU. Namely, what is happening is that **the loss function decreases ridiculously fast, but the accuracy won't increase a bit** (or, if it does, it gets stuck around 10% or smth). Also, every now and then this happens from an epoch to the next one:
[Loss undergoes HUGE jumps between consecutive epochs, and all this without any changes in accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K52B8.jpg)

I have tried to train the network on another dataset (had to change the last layers in order to match the required dimensions) and the model seemed to be learning in a *normal* way, i.e. the accuracy actually increases and the loss doesn't reach 0.0x in one epoch.

I can't post the script, but the model is an **Encoder-Decoder** network: consecutive Convolutions with increasing number of filters reduce the dimensions of the image, and a specular path of Transposed Convolutions restores the original dimensions. So basically the network only contains:

1. Conv2D
2. Conv2DTranspose
3. BatchNormalization
4. Activation("relu")
5. Activation("sigmoid")
6. concatenate

*6* is used to put together outputs from parallel paths or distant layers; *3* and *4* are used after every Conv or ConvTranspose; *5* is only used as final activation function, i.e. as output layer.

I think the problem is pretty generic and I am honestly surprised that I couldn't find a single question about it. What could be happening here? The problem must have something to do with TF/Keras versions, but I can't find any documentation about it and I have been trying to change so many things but nothing changes. It's crazy because if I didn't know that the model works I would try to rewrite it from scratch so I am afraid that this problem may occurr with a new network and I won't be able to understand whether it's the libraries or the model itself.

Thank you in advance! :)

**EDIT**

Code snippets:

- Convolutional block:

```py
encoder1 = Conv2D(filters=first_layer_channels, kernel_size=2, strides=2)(input)
encoder1 = BatchNormalization()(encoder1)
encoder1 = Activation('relu')(encoder1)
```

- Decoder

```py
decoder1 = Conv2DTranspose(filters=first_layer_channels, kernel_size=2, strides=2)(encoder4)
decoder1 = BatchNormalization()(decoder1)
decoder1 = Activation('relu')(decoder1)
```

- Final layers:

```py
final = Conv2D(filters=total, kernel_size=1)(decoder4)
final = BatchNormalization()(final)
Last_Conv = Activation('sigmoid')(final)
```

The task is human pose estimation: the network (which, I recall, works on this specific task with Keras 2.2.4) has to predict twenty binary maps containing the positions of specific keypoints.

Comment: This question does not have enough detail, please do not try to describe code or behavior, instead include code and plots. You did not even mention what task is being trained.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I edited the question. I didn't provide any details because the network works in Keras 2.2.4 (it still does if I downgrade the version), because it's a valid model specifically built for this task. I want to know if anyone has had the same  problem as me when shifting from Keras 2.2.4 to Keras or Tensorflow 2.4.